# How can I define a variable in another namespace within a function/macro in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I'm experimenting with `ns` in *Clojure*, here's what I try:

```
user=> (in-ns 'some-ns)
#<Namespace some-ns>
some-ns=> (def aa 100)
#'some-ns/aa
some-ns=> (in-ns 'user)
#<Namespace user>
user=> (= some-ns/aa 100)
true
user=> (= user/aa 100)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: user/aa, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:5:1) ;this works as expected
user=> (defn function [] (in-ns 'some-other-ns) (def cc 100) (in-ns 'user))
#'user/function
user=> (function)
#<Namespace user>
user=> (= some-other-ns/cc 100)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: some-other-ns/cc, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:8:1)
user=> (= user/cc 100)
true
```

I'm confused, why it doesn't work in function? Also, I tried following:

```
user=> (binding [*ns* (create-ns 'some-a-ns)] (def dd 100))
#'user/dd
user=> (= some-a-ns/dd 100)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: some-a-ns/dd, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:11:1) 
user=> (= user/dd 100)
true
```

according to [clojure doc](http://clojure.org/special_forms#def)

> Creates and interns or locates a global var with the name of symbol and a namespace of the value of the current namespace (*ns*).

what I'm missing?

PS. I know I can use `(intern 'some-ns 'a 100)`, but what I really want is a generic function/macro to do like

```
(with-ns 'some-ns (def a 100))
(= some/a 100)
```

Comment: I do not suggest using this, but this would work: `(do (in-ns 'some-a-ns) (def dd 100))` - defines `dd` as `some-a-ns/dd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`intern` is the correct solution and you can use it in any functions / macros of your own. (Functions can call `intern`; macros can expand to code calling `intern`.)

`def` should only ever be used directly at top level or nested within top-level forms where it will be immediately executed as soon as the top-level form is. So, `def` in `let` is fine, `def` inside a function is not.

`def` receives special handling from the compiler in that the Vars defined by `def` forms are actual created as soon as the `def` is compiled; the initial bindings specified in `def` forms are installed, however, if and when the flow of control actually reaches the `def` form. This explains why the `binding` example doesn't work -- it is the compile-time value of `*ns*` which counts, while the binding introduced by this `binding` form will come into effect at run time.

Finally, if you absolutely insist on using `def` forms to create Vars at runtime, the way to do it is with `eval`:

```
(binding [*ns* some-ns]
  (eval '(def foo 1)))

;; some-ns/foo comes into existence with a root binding of 1
```

Note that here `def` does occur at top-level and will be immediately executed after compilation.

Comment: I'll skip the standard comments about the high runtime cost of `eval` in this answer.